# Python 2.7.10 : How can i stop the user exploiting input by entering equation instead of integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
x2 = (randint(0, 1000000))
y2 = (randint(0, 1000000))

ans2 = input("2. Answer to " + str(x2) + "-" + str(y2))
if ans2 ==  x2 - y2:
  print("Correct!")
  CorrectAns = CorrectAns + 1
else:
  print("Wrong!")
```

My goal: to ask question i.e 1-1 without user inputting 2-2 and getting it correct

Dilemna:
if the person wrote 2-2 when asked, which is 0, which is also the answer to 1-1, the computer thinks it is correct. How do i prevent this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Don't use `input()` *at all*. Only allow integer input, see duplicate.

Comment: Didn't know how to phrase the question. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input(...)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))` in Python 2, so you are evaluating what the user typed in. For example, the input `'10 - 3'` becomes `7` after evaluation.

Get the user input as a string with `raw_input`, convert the string to an integer using the `int` builtin and then check against `x2 - y2`.

Comment: How do i convert the string with int builting?

Comment: I had a crash course in Python now so I now know how to int builting works. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Get the input as raw input and compare it to the stringversion of the result:

```
from  random import randint
x2 = (randint(0, 1000000))
y2 = (randint(0, 1000000))

ans2 = raw_input("2. Answer to " + str(x2) + "-" + str(y2))
if ans2 ==  str(x2 - y2):
  print("Correct!")
  CorrectAns = CorrectAns + 1
else:
  print("Wrong!")
```

This way they can still input the calculation you presented them, but it wont be evaluated to a number anymore. By comparing str with str they must match the exact result and you get around `try: except:` that you need to guards against textinputs if you convert the input to a number for comparison.

---

With conversion is more lenient:

```
from  random import randint

CorrectAns = 0

x2 = (randint(0, 1000000))
y2 = (randint(0, 1000000))

ans2 = raw_input("2. Answer to " + str(x2) + "-" + str(y2)+"\n")
try: 
    ansNum = int(ans2)    
    if ansNum ==  x2 - y2:
      print("Correct!")
      CorrectAns = CorrectAns + 1
    else:
      print("Wrong!")
except ValueError:   # catch conversion errors if other things than int inputted
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Don't convert the `x2 - y2` result to a string, convert the `ans2` string to an integer. Otherwise whitespace around, or a `+` before, or whitespace between a sign and the correct answer would be seen as incorrect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters agreed. but by comparing against string you avoid having to guard against malicious textinputs of "fourtytwo" - its strict and converting to int is more comfortable though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters convinced. added the second version as well.

Comment: You don't have to guard against malicious text inputs. `raw_input()` returns a string, always, and **that's it**. You then use `try: intvalue = int(ans2)`, `except ValueError: # tell user to use integers only, loop or abort`. There is no possibility of abuse here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  You can avoid Try/Except if you do not convert text to int at all. It will simply output wrong in case of "fourtytwo" inputs. With conversion and exceptionhandling is better - I added it already.